# iTunes Store Operation Failed, Missing required icon file

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to update my apps for iOS 11 but everyone of them fails with the same errors on distribution.  I have not changed any of my icons from iOS 10 but i have added the 1024x1024px Marketing Icon as it now is needed in AppIcon. My image sizes when checked are the correct sizes and are all .png has anyone else found this problem in Xcode 9 and if so how did you fix it? here is 2 screenshots showing my icons without warnings in Xcode and then the error message when i try and upload the archive.

Many Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Do you use cocoapods in your project?

Comment: I've tried 3 of my apps, 1 has cocoapods and the other 2 haven't but the same errors on all of them unfortunately.

Comment: Try the solution explained by vladimirdanila in this link:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86290
I hope this helps.

Comment: Exactly the same thing is happening for me. Do you have an iMessage component - my app does. Someone suggested that was to blame.

Comment: Update: Yup, removing the Message component from my app allowed it to pass store validation.

Comment: @CraicDesign it does indeed, I managed to get mine uploaded keeping the iMessage app using the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some users identified a app icon issue using cocoapods and ios 11. Try add add the following code to the Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
    copy_pods_resources_path = "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-IconTest/Pods-IconTest-resources.sh"
    string_to_replace = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"'
    assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}" --app-icon "${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME}" --output-partial-info-plist "${BUILD_DIR}/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist"'
    text = File.read(copy_pods_resources_path)
    new_contents = text.gsub(string_to_replace, assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments)
    File.open(copy_pods_resources_path, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
end
```

For more explanations about this temporary solution check:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7003

Credits to khomTima(https://github.com/khomTima)

If you don't use cocoapods, you can try the solution explained by vladimirdanila in Apple Developer forum.

You need latest version of Sierra and than archive your app. After this click using right button and Show in Finder, than open the package contents and open this file inside of it:  /Products/Application/yourApp.app/info.plist

In there you have to change all the DTXXX Values to be the same as in the latest version of Xcode 8.

```
DTXcode - “0833”  
DTSDKName - “iphoneos10.3"  
DTSDKBuild - “14E8301”  
DTPlatformName - “iphoneos”  
DTCompiler - “com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0”  
DTXcodeBuild - “8E3004b”  
DTPlatformVersion - “10.3”  
DTPlatformBuild - “14E8301"
```

Save the plist file and go back to xcode where you need to export the archive for the App Store.
Last but not least download Application Loader 3.0 from Apple and upload the just generated IPA file.

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.0.dmg

Credits to vladimirdanila(https://forums.developer.apple.com/people/vladimirdanila)

Comment: Hi Michael unfortunately it's even happening to apps I haven't used Cocoapods with :(

Comment: DTXXX Values finally solved my issue.  Do you think I need to do this every time I upload a new version?  That is what I am doing now, but it is pain..

Answer (score 1):

Check in image, first row last image group.  I think size for "iPhone App iOS 7-11 60 pt" group's first image is not 120x120.
And same for second last row group image size must be 167x167 and not 85.5x85.5

Comment: All images are of correct size and were fine when using Xcode 8 and iOS 10.  This seems to be an ongoing problem for many users :(